# java.lang.VerifyError in extending property with kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I try to extend a number type property of Java class with kotlin like this:

```
// Java class
public class Person {
    private Number old;

    public Number getOld() {
        return old;
    }

    public void setOld(Number a) {
        this.old = a;
    }
}
```

and my Kotlin code:

```
// Kotlin code
var Person.age: Number
    inline get() = old
    inline set(value) { old = value }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val person = Person()
    person.age = 20
}
```

Running the code, it gives error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad local variable type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    net/wenris/fx10/EntryKt.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @20: aload_3
  Reason:
    Type integer (current frame, locals[3]) is not assignable to reference type
  Current Frame:
...
```

What's wrong here?

By the way, if I remove inline keyword of the set() method, it goes fine.

Comment: Where is your `old` value in `Person` of Kotlin?

Comment: Congratulations! You just found another bug in kotlin compiler, which is sort of common if you keep using kotlin. Remember Kotlin is a rather yound language that contains lots of bug. It's generally tolerable but is troublesome in many edge cases.

Comment: @Wenris Please file an issue here: http://kotl.in/issue

Comment: Kotlin does not "commonly" have compiler bugs and if you do find one there is usually a work around.  And you should report this, since you already have the work around, it is good to let the team know about it.